# Comparing two numpy arrays and removing elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have been going through several solutions, but I am not able to find a solution I need.

I have two `numpy` arrays. Let's take a **small example** here.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [3,4,5]
```

I want to compare x and y, and remove those values of x that are in y.

So I expect my final_x to be

```
final_x = [1,2,6,7,8,9]
```

I found out that [**np.in1d**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) returns a boolean array the same length as `x` that is True where an element of `x` is in `y` and False otherwise. But how do I use it, if not any other method to get my `final_x`.??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply pass the negated version of boolean array returned by `np.in1d` to array `x`:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
>>> y = [3,4,5]
>>> x[~np.in1d(x, y)]
array([1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: What does the `~` mean here?

Comment: It means negation, e.g. `[True, False, False]` becomes `[False, True, True]`

Comment: In numpy >= 1.8, `in1d` has an `invert` optional keyword argument which, if set to `True`, returns the negated mask directly, and does so faster than negating it yourself, see [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html).

Answer (score 6):

If you really do have numpy arrays then you can use [`numpy.setdiff1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) as below

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
y = np.array([3,4,5])

z = np.setdiff1d(x, y)
# array([1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in sets:

```
final_x = set(x) - set(y)
```

and subtract the second from the first. You can convert `final_x` to a `list` or `numpy.array` if you feel so inclined.