# Removing matching elements from two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider two sorted `numpy` arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,4,4,6,8,10,10,21])
b = np.array([3,3,4,6,10,18,22])
```

How do I:
1. Find the elements that appear in both lists, and
2. Remove only *one* instance of that occurrence from each list.

That is the output should be:

```
a = [1,2,4,8,10,21]

b = [3,3,18,22]
```

So even if there are duplicates, only one instance is removed. However if the lists are

```
c = np.array([1,2,4,4,6,8,10,10,10,21])
d = np.array([3,3,4,6,10,10,18,22])
```

I expect to obtain the new outputs:

```
c = [1,2,4,8,10,21]

d = [3,3,18,22]
```

which is the same as above. The difference is the number of 10's in the list. Each of the two 10's in list `d` takes away one 10 each from `c` leaving the same result.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269476/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-and-removing-elements) was the closest match to my question, but it removed *all* instances of repeats from both lists.

Comment: What happens if you have a = `[1,2,4,4,6,8,10,10,10,21]` and `b = [3,3,4,6,10,10,18,22]`

Comment: @DanielMesejo, the output should be the same in that case such that a = [1,2,4,8,10,21] and b = [3,3,18,22]. I.e. all values are checked and only removed if it is matched with its counterpart in the other array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 10, 10, 21])
b = np.array([3, 3, 4, 6, 10, 18, 22])

ca = Counter(a)
cb = Counter(b)

result_a = sorted((ca - cb).elements())
result_b = sorted((cb - ca).elements())

print(result_a)
print(result_b)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 10, 21]
[3, 3, 18, 22]
```

It returns the same result for (as expected):

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 10, 10, 10, 21])
b = np.array([3, 3, 4, 6, 10, 10, 18, 22])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the indices of first occurences of intersecting items using `np.searchsorted` as following and then remove them using `np.delete()` function:

```
In [58]: intersect = a[np.in1d(a, b)]
In [59]: mask1 = np.searchsorted(a, intersect)

In [60]: mask2 = np.searchsorted(b, intersect)

In [61]: np.delete(a, mask1)
Out[61]: array([ 1,  2,  4,  8, 10, 21])

In [62]: np.delete(b, mask2)
Out[62]: array([ 3,  3, 18, 22])
```

Comment: I was looking to plug into searchsorted but couldn't see this. Very elegant. The numpythonicest of all the answers.

Comment: This is a great method. But it doesn't account for a triple occurrence of 10 (for example) in one list and two in the other. The output should remain the same. See a clear description in the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're looking to do based on the question, but I have been able to duplicate the output using the methods described.

```
import numpy as np

# List of b that are not in a
a = np.array([1,2,4,4,6,8,10,10,21])
b = np.array([3,3,4,6,10,18,22])
newb = [x for x in b if x not in a]
print(newb)

# REMOVE ONE DUPLICATED ELEMENT FROM LIST
import collections
counter=collections.Counter(a)
print(counter)
newa = list(a)
for k,v in counter.items():
    if v > 1:
        newa.remove(k)
print(newa)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the verbosity:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,4,4,6,8,10,10,21])
b = np.array([3,3,4,6,10,18,22])

common_values = set(a) & set(b)

a = a.tolist()
b = b.tolist()

for value in common_values:
    a.remove(value)
    b.remove(value)

a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using for loops:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,4,4,6,8,10,10,21])
b = np.array([3,3,4,6,10,18,22])

for i, val in enumerate(a):
    if val in b:
        a = np.delete(a, np.where(a == val)[0][0])
        b = np.delete(b, np.where(b == val)[0][0])

for i, val in enumerate(b):
    if val in a:
        a = np.delete(a, np.where(a == val)[0][0])
        b = np.delete(b, np.where(b == val)[0][0])

print(a)
print(b)
```

Outputs:

```
[1,2,4,8,10,21]
[3,3,18,22]
```

Comment: This is really inefficient. That's O(N^2) I believe just in the searching, and one of them is a Python loop which will be slower than `np.where()`. And you do it twice. Not to mention the copying of the numpy array on the delete operation

Comment: I've tried to get a grip on the time complexity of this but it's going to take me time to get my head around it. What I can say is that this is possibly one of the most inefficient approaches I have seen and I think you should reconsider your use of numpy if you're going to work like this. Please don't use numpy like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a numpy approach:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,4,4,6,8,10,10,21])
b = np.array([3,3,4,6,10,18,22])

# join and sort (with Tim sort this should be O(n))
ab = np.concatenate([a,b])
i = ab.argsort(kind="stable")
abo = ab[i]

# mark 1st of each group of equal values
d = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(abo,prepend=abo[0]-1,append=abo[-1]+1))
# mark sorted total by origin (a -> False, b -> True)
ig = i>=len(a)
# compare origins of first and last of each group of equal values
# if they are different mark for deletion
dupl = ig[d[:-1]] ^ ig[d[1:]-1]

# finally, delete
ar = np.delete(a,i[d[:-1][dupl]])
br = np.delete(b,i[d[1:][dupl]-1]-len(a))

# inspect
ar
array([ 1,  2,  4,  8, 10, 21])
br
array([ 3,  3, 18, 22])
```